# extract elements between two number from a matrix/vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, extract

For example, I have a 4x4 matrix

```
   A = [1,    2,    3,    4;
        2,    1,    4,    3;
        1,    2,    4,    3;
        4,    1,    2,    3;];
```

For each row, I want to extract the elements between 1 and 3 (assume the matrix always has some elements between 1 and 3, and 1 always comes before 3). For example, return a cell like [{2}, {4}, {2,4}, {2}], or even better with a matrix

```
B=  [0,    1,    0,    0;
     0,    0,    0,    1;
     0,    1,    0,    1;
     0,    1,    0,    0;];
```

Now I am doing a loop for each row, find the index of 1 and 3, then set the index between them to be zero, i.e.,

```
    B = zeros(4,4);
    for i = 1 : size(A,1)
        ind1 = find(A(i,:) ==1);
        ind2 = find(A(i,:) ==3);
        B(i, A(i,ind1+1:ind2-1) ) = 1;
    end
```

Any easier way to generate this matrix B or just the cell? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I dont udnerstand how between is defined. you mean a point where you can find `[1 2 3]` ?   I dont understand the 3rd row of `B`.

Comment: and also the fourth I'd say

Comment: GameOfThrows's B seems correct to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, this might not be a Easier solution, but it does remove the loop, so it should be computationally faster:

The idea is instead of trying to find the numbers between 1 and 3 and set them to 1, I am going to find the numbers outside 1 and 3 and set those to 0:

```
B=zeros(4,4);
B(A == 1) = 1;
B(A == 3) = 1;
C = cumsum(B')';
B(C>=2) =1;
B(C< 1) =1;

%finally you want to invert this:
B = (B-1)*-1;

>> B =

 0     1     0     0
 0     0     1     0
 0     1     1     0
 0     0     1     0
```

========== This part applies after your second EDIT ==========

```
 D = A.*B % this seems to be the cell indexes you are after?

 D =

 0     2     0     0
 0     0     4     0
 0     2     4     0
 0     0     2     0

E = zeros(4,4);
for t = 1:size(A,1)
   E(t,D(t,D(t,:)>0)) = 1;  %This re-applies the index numbers and create a new index matrix through a loop........
   %or you can use E(t,D(t,~~D(t,:))) = 1 to same effect, Thanks to @Dev-iL
end


>> E =

 0     1     0     0
 0     0     0     1
 0     1     0     1
 0     1     0     0
```

This will give you the indexes of the elements between 1 and 3 for A, you can then use logical indexes to find the cell numbers you want.

Comment: But this B is different from OPs B

Comment: @AnderBiguri because he did A.*B at the end, let me put that in.

Comment: But.... This is still different to what OP shows in his post, rigth? (it has been edited, I see now)

Comment: @AnderBiguri sorry, fixed, but that loop is nasty, I might change it

Answer (score 2):

My solution is not very different from what was already suggested, but it has a `bsxfun`, so I say - why not? :)

```
function B = q38307616

A = [1,    2,    3,    4;
     2,    1,    4,    3;
     1,    2,    4,    3;
     4,    1,    2,    3;];

At = A.';

tmp = arrayfun(@colon,find(At==1)+1,find(At==3)-1,'UniformOutput',false);
% [tmp{:}] gives us the indices of the elements we should be considering

B = 0*A; %preallocation
for ind1 = 1: numel(tmp)
  B(ind1,:) = sum(bsxfun(@eq,At(tmp{ind1}).',1:4),1); %1:4 are the allowable values
end
```

"Bonus": another way of getting the logical map of elements between 1 and 3 on each row, which is identical to [**GameOfThrows**'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38308755/3372061) `B`, is by:

```
tmp2 = reshape(full(sparse(~~[tmp{:}],[tmp{:}],~~[tmp{:}],1,numel(A)).'),size(A));
```